# FlexUnit: Can I unit test File Upload?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flexunit, flexunit4

Can I use FlexUnit to unit test a File Upload and delete? Are those actions good examples of unit testing?

I'm a little new to unit testing and trying to figure out what parts of my UI are suitable for unit tests.

Thanks for any helpful tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual file operations will always be executed by native classes (such as FileReference), which you should not try to unit test - that's Adobe's responsibility, at least until Flex has left the Apache incubator.

As a rule of thumb: Always unit test only the code you wrote yourself.  You can decouple it by replacing all external dependencies with test doubles (i.e. stubs or mocks, for example using [mockolate](http://mockolate.org/)).

Comment: I see, I'd be unit testing FileReference functions. That's a waste.

Comment: Yup, so the way to go is mock FileReference and verify that all the calls to its API are made in the correct sequence, rather than trying to simulate an actual upload.